# Resize NavigationController in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

This could be a daft question, but is there a way to resize the Navigation Controller in a storyboard? It simply takes up too much screen space.

Most of my views are pop-overs at the right size but then have a huge iPad size Navigation Controller next to them.

This is purely for visual work in Interface Builder as I have about 20 different screens and it's getting a bit crowded.

Comment: How exactly do you want it to appear? Can you show some more info or some screenshots, maybe.

Comment: I've not found a way to resize nav controllers. Rather annoying. Seems like an immature aspect of Storyboard in IB.