# Is there a reason for the huge Navigation Controller icons in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I've got six VCs at this point in my app. Is there some reason I also need six huge Navigation Controllers? I've never used them (the NC icons) in my development schemes to this point. Here's what my storyboard looks like:

[image]

I'd much prefer to have all that wasted real estate for actual development. Poking around, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988168/resize-navigationcontroller-in-interfacebuilder) on the same subject from 2012, but no answers. The static Navigation Controller icons were apparently an irritant even when they were small. Now they're a huge irritant.

If someone can give me a good reason for their massive, apparently useless footprint, or a way to minimize them, I'll shut up. But it seems they're just a bloody nuisance that Apple could easily fix.

Thanks!

Comment: Undeniably true. OTOH, if everybody here knew exactly what they were doing (or not doing) at all times, there would be no need for any of us to be here, true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is 1 navigation controller, (the first one) for each tab (in your case 1 navigation controller on the first tab , and 1 for the second tab), and then just connect the other viewControllers with the push segue.

**Exaple:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: OK, I get that. But the other views are presented modally, and come up with no navigation bar, and I wanted a Cancel and Save button at the top. I admit I need to study the various methods of presentation some more, but have used the "Embed in Navigation Controller" menu item before.

Comment: Yes, if you want then present a view modally, then its best to imbed it into the navigion controller.

Comment: Thanks, Dejan. I guess I'll just have to put up with these monsters.

Comment: @dejan--I accepted your answer because it pretty much answers the question about the number of NCs. I'd still like to know why the things need to be so big, but so far nobody has an answer. Thanks!

Comment: What to you mean with "big"? Do you mean the size in the storyboard?

Comment: Exactly, the size in the storyboard. They seem a waste of space.